# FTP/Import test cases to TFS server

Tags: tfs, import, export, mtm

I need help to import testcases to TFS from excel sheet. I am already aware of the tool Test Case Migrator Plus. But i am looking for another alternative since this tool is blacklisted in my company. Any help or info regarding this is appreciated. Isnt there a way in MTM to handle this ?

Thanks,
Aravind Suriaraj

Answer (score 2):

The Test Case Migrator (aka tcmimport) is the tool that I use - and most other TFS Consultants I know use.

http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/

Is there some reason this tool is unacceptable to your company?  What makes you think any other tool would be acceptable?

Alternatively, you can use the Grid View in WebTCM to copy-paste test cases from Excel.

http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2013-sep-9-vso

Comment: Thanks Dylan for the response. For reasons unknown this tool is blocked and i do not have more information on that. And the Grid view in WebTCM, is it available for TFS 2012 as well? I am not seeing that option here.

Comment: Grid View is not available in 2012.  Another option is to write some code yourself against the TFS API, but at that point you're basically just reimplementing tcmimport yourself...